# How to make a query to view a specific ID/ 1 line

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQNnU.png)

I have in mind that selecting such goes with the query like this

```
Select * from tablename where orderID = 1
```

how do i make not only work with 1 order id but works all view buttons depending which order ID i click to view

Comment: Use IN with orderID.

Comment: you pass the order id in previous page

Comment: <a href="page.php?id=order id"></a>

Answer (score 1):

In your list file use anchor like this, in which pass the id of order

```
<a href="file.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Click For More Details</a>
```

And in request file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $query = 'select * from tablename where orderID = "'.$id.'"';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set it in the link with the view

```
<a href="view.php?order=<?php echo $orderID;?>">View</a>
```

And then on your receipt page before running the query you would do something such as

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['order'];
$sql = "Select * from orders where orderID = '{$id}'";
//execute sql and display...
```